# Mule AMQP connector: Value is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration

Tags: mule, amqp, mule-studio, properties-file, spring-amqp

I'm trying to read a property from a configuration file (.properties) in Mule but it seems not to take the value from it.

These are my configuration and properties files:

#### dev.properties File

```
amqp.host=localhost
amqp.port=5672
amqp.username=guest
amqp.password=guest
amqp.ackMode=MANUAL
amqp.prefetchCount=1
```

#### XML Configuration File

```
<context:property-placeholder location="dev.properties"/>

<amqp:connector 
    name="amqpLocalhostConnector"
    host="${amqp.host}"
    port="${amqp.port}"
    username="${amqp.username}"
    password="${amqp.password}"
    ackMode="${amqp.ackMode}"
    prefetchCount="${amqp.prefetchCount}" />
```

When I execute the application, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR 2015-06-29 12:04:33,540 [main]
org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '${amqp.ackMode}' is not
facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[AMQP_AUTO, MULE_AUTO, MANUAL]'.
It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

If I set the property like this:

```
    ackMode="MANUAL"
```

the application runs without a problem.

How can I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Ack Mode: Is the properties which is already set by Mule in drop down box. You can directly select it.Rest of the properties you can read( userName, pwd etc) from property file.Any specific reason why you were reading  ack Mode in property file?.

Comment: if your flow using two ack mode, example 'Manual' and 'Mule_Auto'. Can use two AMQP connectors with respect to config.

Comment: @star thanks for writing! I did not understand your first comment, do you say that I can select the AckMode property from a drop down box? Which one?
Regarding the 2nd comment, I would like to share the same connector with many mule apps, each one with a particular properties file.